# X11 forwarding works on Ubuntu using Windows 10 cmd-line ssh only after first using Putty

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, x11, xming

Note: X11 forwarding works fine if I use putty and X11 forwarding using localhost:0.0.  I would like to get it to work using Windows 10 command line ssh.
Here are my steps.

- My Windows 10 computer and my Ubuntu computer are on the same local network.
- I installed and ran Xming. The icon in my icon tray says Xming Server:0.0
- I open a command window  (type `cmd`)
- I use `ssh -X mymachine` and log in ok.
- At my Ubuntu prompt, I type

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
xcalc
```

- I get the following message

```
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
```

- I tried other combinations (Note: Windows 10 computer is on 192.168.1.18)

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
export DISPLAY=192.168.1.18:0.0
export DISPLAY=192.168.1.18:0
export DISPLAY=10:0.0
export DISPLAY=10:0.0.1
```

I even tried typing the following in the Windows command window:

```
set DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
ssh -X mymachine
```

but Windows didn't like that.
I also tried using Windows Powershell.
Nothing worked. I kept getting the same message.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. 
I used Putty again and checked the $DISPLAY variable and got:

```
echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

I just used the value 10.0 and it worked for both the cmd-shell and the Powershell.

But get this ...  I tried the same thing the next day (after a restart on both machines) and it did not work.

I used `ssh -X mymachine` and logged in
typed `xcalc` and got the same error message.

(My $DISPLAY was set in my .bash_profile so I didn't need to reset it.)

I then tried Putty again, and it worked and $DISPLAY was set to localhost:10.0

I then returned to the open cmd-shell and typed `xcalc` and it worked.  I didn't do anything in that shell window prior.  Here is the output

```
adrian@MyMachine:~$ xcalc
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
adrian@MyMachine:~$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
adrian@MyMachine:~$ xcalc
adrian@MyMachine:~$
```

It appears that Putty is doing something globally that has an effect on other shells without the need to reload. How is that so?

Comment: Woo, thanks, this trick also works for me, I have been trying to use VS code to connect to the remote but never success, with the Putty, things work like a magic!

Answer (score 1):

Xming Server:0.0 on Windows 10 computer with IP address 192.168.1.18

so the only way to connect to this X11-Server will be to

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.1.18:0.0
```

If there are still problems, check if you have enabled X11-forwarding in your putty client.
You will find this under Putty Configuration > Connection > SSH > X11
Don't forget to save the Session after setting the X11-forwarding if you plan to use this setting more than one time. Session > Saved Sessions (put in name for your session) > Save

There is also the possiblity to run into a problem with the Xming Server.
Right-click the Xming Server icon in the taskbar and view log. If there is a line "IP address not permitted" you will have to edit the file X0.hosts in the installation folder of Xming.
Add the IP address of you Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Local (Windows 10, Xming server)

Server (Raspberry Pi 4, RaspberryPi OS)

Ssh Client (Windows native ssh client)

Open windows command prompt and type ***set DISPLAY=localhost:0.0***, then ***ssh -Y  user@ip***. Use ***-X*** for untrusted session. Works just fine.